# Passing Image to procedure in Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, image, vba

I'm new to VBA but have some experience in other languages.

I have the following working code (A Imagezoom) im my UserForm1:

```
public Dim zoomed As Boolean
zoomed = False

Image1_MouseMove(...)

If zoomed = False Then
zoomed = True

Image1.Left = Image1.Left - (Image1.Width*2 - Image1.Width)
Image1.Top = Image1.Top - (Image1.Height*2 - Image1.Height)

Image1.Height = Image1.Height * 2
Image1.Width = Image1.Width * 2
End If
```

Now I want to give this to a procedure in a Module but I keep struggling:

- Passing as MSForms.Image gives me only Options like ImageEffects, etc
- Passing as Image does not work either (Is the same?)
- Passing as Shape/ShapeRange gives me incompatible Types-Error
- Passing as StdImage gives me the .Width and .Height but not .Top and
  .Left
- Passing as Object lets me read (f.e. MsgBox) .Width, .Height, .Left
  and .Top but I can't change it - even if I pass it ByRef. If I add
  "Set" it throws an Error with "Object needed"?

Is it possible to see all Items of Image1 in the objectbrowser? If I search Image I can find the specific Items of Image1 but not the general object Items of Image1 - though I can call it from the procedure itself.
I tried searching for Top and Left but can't figure this out.

Thanks for your Help

Comment: They are there to set, not showing in intellisense, I used the following `Public Function AlterImage(ByRef img As Image)
img.Height = 2 * img.Height
End Function`  and it worked. Called by `AlterImage Me.Image1`  Not sure why they don't show..

Comment: If you do the code, `Dim I as image, set I=me.image1`, the properties are also not there, so I would suggest that its available from Me.Image1 only.  Passing it as a control, gives you these, but you lose the image properties, so I'd say it is a control in the form context, but containing an image, and you're passing the image, so I think you'll need to pass the control, and access the image..

Comment: @Nathan_Sav
The problem is not the .Height (I can change that by passing it as StdImage) - the problem is the .Top and .Left

Can you give me an code-example for passing the control to the procedure and then accessing the image?

Comment: Public Function x(i As Control) look at the locals window in the code, the properties of the form objects.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not as advanced as you may think so I have to ask more specific:
In my `Image1_move(...)` I  `Call zoom(Image1)` and then in my `public sub zoom(i As Control)` I can `i.Left = i.Left * 2` ? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to track if an image has been zoomed in.  Instead of using a class variable for each image you could use the image's tag property.

```
Sub MoveImage(Image1 As MSForms.Image)

    If Not Image1.Tag = "Zoomed" Then
        Image1.left = Image1.left - (Image1.Width * 2 - Image1.Width)
        Image1.Top = Image1.Top - (Image1.Height * 2 - Image1.Height)

        Image1.Height = Image1.Height * 2
        Image1.Width = Image1.Width * 2
        Image1.Tag = "Zoomed"
    End If

End Sub
```

### Update

When passing a `MSForms.Image` to a sub only the `Image` properties are available to IntelliSense.  Properties such as `Top, Left, Width and Height` belong to the `MSForms.Control` base class.  Becuase the `MSForms.Image` default value returns a `MSForms.Control` you will still be able to modify those properties.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TestMSFormsControl Image1, Image1
End Sub

Sub TestMSFormsControl _
    (Ctrl As MSForms.Control, Img As MSForms.Image)
    Stop
End Sub
```

In the demonstration below I pass an `MSForms.Image` to a subroutine in a public module both as a `MSForms.Control` and a `MSForms.Image`.  Notice that the `Left` property of `Img As MSForms.Image` isn't available to Intellisense but can still be read and modified.

[image]

### MSForms Image

[image]

### MSForms Control

[image]

Comment: But the code itself is perfectly working in the (Userform1)MouseMove-Event itself - the problem is, that I want do do this with multiple images and therefore want to do it in a procedure in my Module1. How can I pass the Image to the procedure and then be able to change `Left` and `Top` ?
Furthermore I have a public boolean zoomed which goes to true when the event fired once so this is taken care of (did not include it in my code above to keep it clean)

Comment: @OliverBecker I misunderstood your problem.  I updated my answer.

Comment: When I pass it as `MSForms.Image` I can only call functions like `.Imageeffect`etc when I tried but not even `.Width` (As stated in my original Post this is possible with `As StdPicture` - but with no method i can change `.Top` and `.Left`)  This is what I want to do, but these propertys seem to be not part of the MSForms.Image class.@

Comment: This is exactly what I searched for! Will try it as soon as I come home - Thank you very much for the work you put in this answer especially for the pics and the gif!
Now - I searched like you did in the object explorer but do you have a hint how I can get a list of all "Actions" I can do with my Image1 to find the connection to MSForms.Control myself the next time when I have a similar case (Instead of searching for '.Top' and finding a mass of classes(Shape/ShapeRange/Object/Control....) who use it trying to guess which one I have to pass?

Comment: @OliverBecker all the `MsForms.Controls` return a  `MsForms.Control` object as their default value.  This means you can use all the `MsForms.Control` properties as well as the control specific properties.  I have images of the properties in my answer.

Comment: Yes and your Images are great - my question now is more unspecific for future reference so I dont have to ask questions like my main question again: If there is a way to see all Members of an specific Object with their parent-class. I did search for Image like you did and from there clicking the Member Picture I came to StdImage and was able to get the Member `.Width` - but how do I get all the Classes f.e. `Image1`uses including MSForms.Image, MSForms.Control? Like if it was not for you and Stackoverflow - how could I have found the Connection between my Image1 and the MSForms.Control myself?

Comment: @OliverBecker I think that the easiest approach would be to use a direct reference to the `Image` control while writing the code and switch to the local variable while testing.  So you will have two `With` statements: `With Userform1.Image1` and  `With MyImage`.  While writing the code use `With Userform1.Image1` then comment it out and uncomment  `With MyImage` for testing and deployment.  It's not the prettiest solution by it works.